# Why does going directly to the location of index.html in React nor work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, url-routing

I have my website on the subdirectory `/test` and it only works when I go directly to that path from `www.domain.com/test`. If I go to `domain.com/test`, it redirects to `domain.com/test/index.html` and displays my error page. I am confused if this is an error within React routing or my .htaccess.